# Inconsistent Solution Techniques for Quasilinear PDE

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZrwxQr6aV4), the final step in solving the quasilinear PDE is to write $c_1 = f(c_2)$.  The example used is the Burger Equation $uu_x + u_y = 0$, and the solution is $u = f(x - uy)$.

[image]

However, in [this PDF](https://users.mai.liu.se/vlatk48/teaching/teaching_vt2009/lectures_uu/PDE09-021.pdf), the final step of the same technique is to write $u = f(c_1, c_2)$.  This does not seem equivalent to me.  Applying the above example here we would get $u = f(u, x - uy)$, which does not seem the same as $u = f(x - uy)$.

Are these the same somehow?  Is there a way to convert an arbitrary function of multiple variables into an arbitrary function of one variable?  If not, which solution technique is correct?

As a secondary matter of inquiry, does it matter that this solution is often a multifunction, or is it implied that only choices of $f$ which make $u$ a function are acceptable solutions?

Comment: Where does it say $u = f(c_{1}, c_{2})$ in the pdf? I couldn't see it. If you are referring to the expression $$u = f(x+y+z,x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$$ where $x+y+z = c_{1}, x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = c_{2}$ then this is $u = f(c_{1}, c_{2})$ but this occurs because you are working in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ now, not $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as in the other example. And what do you mean by 'multifunction'?

Comment: @mattos Yeah, that is the part I was referring to.  Is there a general form in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of which these two forms are special cases?  By "multifunction," I mean there are some $xy$-pairs which produce multiple values of $u$.

Comment: Any solution to a first order PDE in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will be written as $\phi(c_{1}, c_{2}, \dots, c_{n}) = 0$ with the $c_{i}$ the characteristic curves and $\phi$ an arbitrary differentiable function. In turn, this can be written as $c_{n} = f(c_{1}, c_{2}, \dots, c_{n-1})$. In your first example, you are working in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and you have $c_{2} = u, c_{1} = x - uy$ so that $u = f(x-uy)$. In the second example you are working in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and you have $c_{3} = u, c_{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}, c_{1} = x + y + z$ so that $u = f(x+y+z, x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$.